# I can't make this callback work

Tags: javascript, object, callback, passport.js

So I have two files

file1.js:

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var query = require( "./file2.js" );

module.exports = function(passport) {

passport.use(
        'local-signup',
        new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {

                 function callback(check) {
                    return check;
                 }

                var m = query.chkUsername(username, callback);
                var n = query.chkMail(req.body.email, callback);
                console.log("m "+m);
                console.log("n "+n);
        })
    );
};
```

file2.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);

module.exports = {
 chkUsername: function(username, callback) {
        var queryString = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        connection.query(queryString,[username], function(err, rows) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
                if (rows.length) {
                    callback(false);
                } else {
                    callback(true);
                }
        });
    },

    chkMail: function(email, callback) {
        var queryString = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?";
        connection.query(queryString,[email], function(err, rows) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
                if (rows.length) {
                    callback(false);
                } else {
                    callback(true);
                }
        });
    }
};
```

How can I do a callback from file2.js back to file1.js and print if query results are false or true?

It is important to use callback and not just a return true or false, because I have another file that uses sockets and those same querys.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: The callback is not working

Answer (score 0):

You are returning something in your callback function however you aren't then actually doing anything with it. `callback(true);` will return true but then you aren't doing anything with it. Did you mean to do `return callback(true);`. Same thing applying to anywhere else where you did `callback(true)` or `callback(false`